# Update twice nested document with C# driver 2.4.4 in MongoDB 3.4.6

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document similar to the following document for storing licenses. Unnecessary fields are deleted.

```
{
  "_id" : "1",
  "company_name" : "stackOverflow",
  "license_holders" : [
    {
      "UID" : "AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD",
      "software_version" : "1.2.3",
      "licenses" : [
        {
          "creation_date" : "03.03.17",
          "is_valid" : true,
          "license_id" : "l1"
        },
        {
          "creation_date" : "03.03.16",
          "is_valid" : false,
          "license_id" : "l2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "UID" : "111-222-333-444",
      "software_version" : "1.2.3",
      "licenses" : [
        {
          "creation_date" : "05.05.17",
          "is_valid" : true,
          "license_id" : "l3"
        },
        {
          "creation_date" : "05.05.16",
          "is_valid" : false,
          "license_id" : "l4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can update a software version with a given UID by this query:

```
    public async Task<Customer> UpdateLicenseHolderSoftwareVersion(string uid, string softwareVersion) {
        var update = Builders<Customer>.Update.Set(c => c.LicenseHolders[-1].CurrentSoftwareVersion, softwareVersion);
        Customer customer = await DMSLicenseCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(c => c.LicenseHolders.Any(h => h.UID == uid), update);
        return customer;
    }
```

I couldn't find a way to update a license's `"is_valid"` field. I am trying to select the correct license with `UID` and `LicenseId` fields. I have tried many things but non of them succeeded. Is it a bad practice to embed this many documents? Or am i missing a way to update and retrieve a few layer nested documents which are inside arrays. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have couple of suggestions you could do to make your life easier.

- I found it useful to not store nested documents as lists but dictionaries. That way you can easily find what subdocument you want to update. For example UID and license_id can be keys in your dictionary and values rest of fields.
- I am not a big fan of identifying something in db that is not primary key. Here you update a subdocument based on UID and license_id. I think that is bad practice and would suggest you change that.
- as for big documents that have lots of nested documents inside them you need to be moderate on how deep you go. More nested documents means slower query executions. I suggest you benchmark your app and check if you are satisfied with speed.

Solution for your current problem:

```
 public async Task ToggleLicesneIsValid(string UID, int licenseId)
    {
        var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.licence_holders, i => i.UID == UID);
        var customer = DMSLicenseCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        var item = customer.licence_holders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UID == UID).licenses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.license_id == licenseId);

        item.is_valid = !item.is_valid;

        await DMSLicenseCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(o => o.mongoId == customer.mongoId, customer);
    }
```

This method toggles true/false on "is_valid" but I suggest you have 2 separate methods (one for setting it true and one for setting it false). That way code is more readable and you can avoid potential bugs.

PS i named id mongoId in my tests but change it to your liking.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, especially for the dictionary one. UID and license_id fields are guaranteed to be unique but they are not primary keys according to mongoDB. I see that your solution replaces the whole document instead of trying to update a field atomically. I am trying to find a way to replace only a license document if possible, not the whole customer document. Thanks for the answer :)